# Bounded Levenberg Maquardt Algorithm implementation in c++

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mathematical-modeling, least-squares

I am getting measurement from sensor which follows sinusoidal model. So I want to find sinusoidal model out of noisy measurement. I am using LM algorithm from C++ Eigen Library but I think it does not provide bounded version (Lower and Upper limit on parameters). Does someone know any other implementation of LM which provides bounded version.

Comment: You can do [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method) to solve the constrained problem with your unconstrained algorithm.